# What are the alternate solution(s) for Load-balancing in MySQL database server

Tags: load-balancing, mysql-proxy

Are there any better choices other than using MySQL-proxy to perform Load-balancing in actual database servers?
MySQL-proxy is in its alpha edition. So I think this solution is not enough tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In market there are other paid tools are available which can handle load balancing, data availability and recovery in case of any disaster.
TeraData and NEC Japan has many such kind of solution available in market for different-2 database servers.

Comment: Can you suggest some opensource alternatives? Freewares will also do.

Comment: HAProxy is an open source software which can load balance HTTP and TCP servers. And if you need a better paid version then you can use NGINX load balancer solution which is very efficient.

Answer (score 3):

You can use HAPROXY for Load-balancing in MySQL database server.
Find details at below location:
http://www.percona.com/live/mysql-conference-2013/sessions/load-balancing-mysql-haproxy